# Parser nesting and result interpretation

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, pyparsing

I'm trying to understand how to organize parsers in *pyparsing*. The expected result is a dictionary that doesn't have duplicates and is not unnecessarily nested. For the purpose I wrote four tests. Their results (found at the bottom) seem confusing to me.

The four different test parsers (*person1*-*person4*) render slightly different results.

My questions:

- Why does the `person2` parser produce additional *name* and *surname* pairs outside the *person* object in the result dictionary?
- Why does adding `setResultsName()` produce a `ParseResults`, instead of a string, as the first element in the result list for the `person4` parser?
- Is it possible to infer how parsers are organized from `ParseResults`? If so, how could one do that?
- The [wikispaces pyparsing page](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) is no longer and I'm wondering if there are any other resources available apart from [the documentation included in the package](https://rawgit.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/master/HowToUsePyparsing.html) and the [pyparsing quick reference](https://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pyparsing/web/index.html).

-

```
from __future__ import print_function

import json
from pyparsing import *


def test(person, result):
    print(person)
    print("result: {}".format(result))
    print("result.asDict():\n" +
          json.dumps(result.asDict(), sort_keys=True, indent=4))
    print("type(result): " + str(type(result)))
    print("type(result[0]): " + str(type(result[0])))
    print("type(result['person']" + str(type(result["person"]))
          if 'person' in result else '')
    print()


name = Word(alphas).setResultsName("name")
surname = Word(alphas).setResultsName("surname")

person1 = Group(name + surname).setResultsName("person")
person2 = (name + surname).setResultsName("person")

person3 = Combine(name + White() + surname)
person4 = Combine(name + White() + surname).setResultsName("person")

people = [person1, person2, person3, person4]
parsers = ['Group(name + surname).setResultsName("person")',
           '(name + surname).setResultsName("person")',
           'Combine(name + White() + surname)',
           'Combine(name + White() + surname).setResultsName("person")',
           ]

enum = 1
for p in people:
    test("person" + str(enum) + ": " +
         parsers[enum - 1], p.parseString("John Doe"))
    enum += 1
```

Executing the above results in the following output:

```
person1: Group(name + surname).setResultsName("person")
result: [['John', 'Doe']]
result.asDict():
{
    "person": {
        "name": "John", 
        "surname": "Doe"
    }
}
type(result): <class 'pyparsing.ParseResults'>
type(result[0]): <class 'pyparsing.ParseResults'>
type(result['person']<class 'pyparsing.ParseResults'>

person2: (name + surname).setResultsName("person")
result: ['John', 'Doe']
result.asDict():
{
    "name": "John", 
    "person": {
        "name": "John", 
        "surname": "Doe"
    }, 
    "surname": "Doe"
}
type(result): <class 'pyparsing.ParseResults'>
type(result[0]): <type 'str'>
type(result['person']<class 'pyparsing.ParseResults'>

person3: Combine(name + White() + surname)
result: ['John Doe']
result.asDict():
{
    "name": "John", 
    "surname": "Doe"
}
type(result): <class 'pyparsing.ParseResults'>
type(result[0]): <type 'str'>


person4: Combine(name + White() + surname).setResultsName("person")
result: [['John Doe']]
result.asDict():
{
    "person": {
        "name": "John", 
        "surname": "Doe"
    }
}
type(result): <class 'pyparsing.ParseResults'>
type(result[0]): <class 'pyparsing.ParseResults'>
type(result['person']<class 'pyparsing.ParseResults'>
```

Comment: I am in the process of migrating the pyparsing support pages over to a GitHub repo, please bear with me.

Comment: For posterity's sake, pyparsing now resides at https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing